# Pushing up content on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to push up some content on hover, I would the text "HELLO" (will later be replaced with an image) to be pushed up by the white background and content on hover, but for some reason it just stays in the same place, I am stuck for ideas now as I have tried several different position types, locations etc. and have had no luck.

My code is

```
<div class="four columns img-overlay" style="position: relative; border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;">
                    <img src="http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/penguin-test.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
                    <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: -11px; right: -11px; z-index: 10;">
                        <img src="http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/new-posts.png">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 50%; transform: translate(0, -50%); text-align: center;">
                        <p style="display: inline-block; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35); font-family: 'Amatic SC'; color: #FFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3a3c3d; margin: 0; padding: 10px; font-size: 38px; line-height: 38px;">Featured One</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h5 style="padding-top: 11px; margin: 0 0 15px 0;">Sub Title</h5>
                        <p style="margin: 0 0 15px 0; padding: 0;">Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!!</p>
                        <p style="margin: 0 0 15px 0; padding: 0 0 20px 0;"><a href="#">Featured Link</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and CSS

```
.img-overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
.img-overlay:hover .overlay,
.overlay:hover {
  height: 70.5%;
  background: #FFF;
}

.img-overlay > img {
  display: block;
}

.img-overlay:after {
  content: "HELLO";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mt5spmt7/

any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: you will get more feedback if you put your code in a fiddle.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll do that now. Thanks!

Comment: and why the mix of inline css and linked css.  Inline css makes everything harder to understand.

Comment: Sorry, it's messy right now, as I'm currently working on it. I understand it must be hard, but any suggestions would be welcome, and I can indeed try them myself :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it part of the moving overlay and move the overflow hidden to the parent

```
.overlay:after { content: "HELLO";}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/tetvvLL4/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you sir! Ah, but one thing I have just noticed, that cuts off the "new" ribbon, can I have that overflow still?

Comment: The .overflow element needs to have a parent with property overflow:hidden so add a new Div that isn't the parent of the ribbon image so it doesnt cutoff the ribbon